# sympy: Incorrect substitution results

Tags: python-2.x, sympy, substitution, symbolic-math

I am unable to evaluate and plot a simple (known) function in sympy within Ipython notebook:

> **y(x) = ( F / 6EI )( x^3 - 3Lx^2 )** where:
>
> - F = 10^6
> - E = 200E9
> - I = (1/12)(0.5*1^3)
> - L = 3

I define the expression using `symbols()` and substitute known values (using `subs()`).

```
import sympy
from sympy import symbols

sympy.init_printing()
from IPython.display import Math, Image
from IPython.display import display


F, E, L, I, x = symbols('F, E, L, I, x')    #Definition of sympy symbols

y = F/(6*E*I) * (x**3 - 3*L*x**2)    #Define beam deflection equation
display(Math("y=" + latex(y)))

y = y.subs({F:10**6, E:200E9, L:3, I:(1/12)*(0.5)*(1**3)})    #Substitute known values to define specific deflection curve
display(Math("y=" + latex(y)))
```

---

However, it results in:

> **y(x) = (infinity)x^3 -(infinity)x^2**

This is clearly incorrect, as the coefficients should be rational numbers - this is the well understood [cantilevered beam deflection equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflection_(engineering)).  It should evaluate to:

> **y(x) = 2E-5*x^3 - 1.8E-4*x^2** where:
>
> - y(x=0) = 0
> - y(x=L) = FL^3 / 3EI.

---

**Why does sympy produce this result and how can I modify my solution to attain the correct solution?**

---

As noted in the comments, the above code works correctly for Python 3 but fails in Python 2.7 (the version I am running).

Comment: Quantity `y` (before and after `subs`) is the correct one when I run your code. Maybe the issue is with the display functions (which you do not provide and I cannot reproduce)

Comment: @Stelios Thanks for your interest.  The `display()` function is imported from Ipython - Ive edited to reflect this.  However,I still get the same result without using  `display()`: You used `print y`?

Comment: Yes, `print(y)` (Python 3) gives the expected result. *However*, in Python 2, `print y` gives the "infinity" result!

Comment: @Stelios Thank you! I am using Python 2.7 - this gives me a workaround at least, and ill add that to the question..

Comment: You substitute `I:(1/12)*(0.5)*(1**3)`. In Python 2, integer division always gives you an integer (rounding down), so `1/12` is 0, I is 0, **6EI** is 0, and you've got a division by zero. Put `from __future__ import division` at the top to get the Python 3 behaviour (`1/12` giving a float) in Python 2. Or use Sympy's Rational class - http://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers

Comment: @ThomasK Beautiful, thank you.  I previously tried `float((1/12)*(0.5*1**3)` with no effect, but I now understand it why that didnt work.  Ive opted to use the `Rational()` class.  Post that as the answer if youd like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Python 2, `1/12` results in 0, due to integer division. You can use `from __future__ import division`, or use Python 3 (I recommend using Python 3), and it will return a float.

Better, though, with SymPy, is to use a rational. If you use `Rational(1, 12)` you will get an exact result. In general, your answers with SymPy will be more accurate if you use exact numbers (rational numbers), and then use `evalf()` to convert the expression to a float at the end.